# Making a histogram of a user defined random variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

Suppose I want to generate a histogram of $n$ trials a slightly complicated random variable in *Mathematica*. Is there an easy way to do this?

For instance, to make a histogram of a normal variable one can simple use

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]]
```

I want to create a histogram of a more complicated random variable. The random variable comes from random matrix theory, but its specific form is probably not so important. If we call it X, running

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[X, 200]]
```

returns

> RandomVariate::udist: "The specification X is not a random distribution recognized by the system." Indeed, even running

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]^2, 200]]
```

returns this error message, and I think if I understood what's going wrong in this latter case my problem would be resolved also.

There is a *Mathematica* [help page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram.html) on the topic, but all the examples of random variables given there are for prepackaged probability distributions.

Comment: Have you looked at ProbabilityDistribution[]

Comment: What do you mean by `NormalDistribution[0, 1]^2`? It is square of the probability density function or `x^2` where `x` distributed as `NormalDistribution[0, 1]`? `TransformedDistribution`, `EmpiricalDistribution` and `SmoothKernelDistribution` can be helpful. Could you provide an example of the distribution?

Comment: Break your problem down to pieces and find the smallest piece that you can't get working.  Do you need to plot the PDF or do you just need to generate a large number of random variates?  It seems to me that you need the latter.  In this case `Histogram` is irrelevant to the question.  `NormalDistribution[0, 1]^2` is not correct syntax.  As george said, look at `ProbabilityDistribution`.

Comment: You don't have a problem with `Histogram`, you have a problem defining a distribution. Have a look at [Create Your Own Distribution Workshop](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8040/).

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are after..

```
Histogram[
  RandomVariate[
    ProbabilityDistribution[
     2 Sqrt[π] (PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]][x])^2, {x, -∞, ∞}], 2000]]
```

Note that the argument to `ProbabilityDistribution[]` has to be a proper probability density function in the sense that it integrates to unity. (Thats where that `2 Sqrt[π]` comes from)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delayed response. This does indeed produce a histogram of X^2 where X is a standard normal variable. I'm afraid I oversimplified the problem in this example though. How would one go about creating a histogram, summing a series of independent identically distributed variables for instance? The actual problem I want to solve concerns operations on the eigenvalues of random matrices. Would it be most appropriate to simply create a new question, or to edit the question above to be more precise?